# UX process for various products in different development phases

Tags: user-research, research, design-process

There are a lot of phases to go through in UX and UI design process. In research phase, there are various research methods available and many steps to take to achieve a meaningful result.

I would like to better understand, what UX research methods would be the most appropriate for projects in these cases?

**1. Website**

- New website
- Existing website - adding new pages, sections, updating any part, redesign

**2. Web app**

- New web app
- Existing web app - adding new pages, sections, updating any part,
  redesign

**3. Mobile app**

- New mobile app
- Existing mobile app - adding new pages, sections, updating any part,
  redesign

Answer (score 1):

I came across this article on medium - "[Which UX Research Method to Use](https://uxplanet.org/which-ux-research-method-to-use-2ca910a9b68e)'. And this is link to the "[whole tree](https://overflow.io/s/E42BS4/)" Let me know if it helps!

[image: Flowchart of methods.]